# Application Crashes When Dismissing Modal View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

There's somewhere in my app that I dismiss `ModalViewController` and it causes app to crash with the following log :

`-[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5c92640`

Can anybody help me finding what the problem is please ?
Any suggestion's really appreciated.

P.S: Here's the full scenario : My app presents a `Modal View Controller` when it receives some kind of notifications ( Incoming call request ), and if the call is being ended before user accept or reject the call, the view controller is being dismissed automatically. However this is what happens in foreground. When the app is in background, if the call end before user enter the app, that "Automatically dismissing view controller" causes this crash.

Comment: Have you checked using Exception breakpoints ?

Comment: Enable Zombie and try to find which object was causing the crash

Comment: provide the code snippet to find the problem

Comment: Yeah, I have used exception breakpoints and no progress there. The log I posted above is printed using Zombie Objects !!!

Comment: ok.can you show me the dismissmodalview code?

Comment: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: This is the deprecated code

Comment: You should use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; and also to present [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];